# RPi Camera and Java: how to check whether video recording has been completed?

Tags: java, command, raspberry-pi3

I have a "VidCamera" class, which basically runs the "raspivid" command tool for recording a video.  The method for recording a video from that class looks like this:

```
public void recordVideo(String filename, int duration) throws IOException {
    setFilename(filename);
    setDuration(duration);
    try {
        String cmdline = getCmdLine();
        Process sysprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while recording video.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the getCmdLine() method is constructed to output something like: `raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -fps 60 - t 5000 -o testvideo.h264`.

The video recording works as expected, since it's simply using the command line tool.  However, my code does not know when the video has finished recording.

Example, when I test the video recording from my main class with:

```
    try {
        camcorder.recordVideo("myVideoTest.h264", 5000);            
        System.out.println("Video recording completed.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

then the text "Video recording completed." is printed immediately after calling the recordVideo() method.  In the background, the 5s video recording is still busy in another thread.

How can I solve this?  How can I make my code know when the video recording from the command line tool is ready?

Comment: One solution would be to find out with another command line whether the camera is still "busy".  But I am not able to find any commands for that.  Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research and some trial and error, I ended up creating this piece of code to check the status of the raspivid process:

```
    public boolean getRecordingStatus() throws IOException {
    // Check from command line tool if process is still running.
    boolean response = true;
    try {
        String cmdResponseLine;
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ps -e | grep raspivid"};
        // Feed the pipe with a String array, does not work with String only.
        Process sysprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sysprocess.getInputStream()));

        if ((cmdResponseLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response = true;
        else
            response = false;

        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while checking for raspivid process...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Using the "*ps -e | grep raspivid*" command, the code checks whether the raspivid process is still alive.  If it is, the command will throw one line of response text.  If the process has finished, there will be no response text.  By interpreting this response, this block of code can return a false or true statement.

Any feedback to this solution is welcome!